# Shift between two characters

Tags: bash

How to get a shift between two characters in bash?

For instance, in C++ we have:

```
'c'-'a'=2
```

Are there any elegant solutions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define `ord` to get the ASCII value of each character (from [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/92448/67817), [Bash FAQ](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/071)):

```
ord() { LC_CTYPE=C printf '%d' "'$1"; }
```

(note that the `'` is not a typo! It is required for `printf` to [treat a character as a number](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/printf.html#tag_04_102_13)<sup>**1**</sup>)

Then you can subtract one from the other:

```
$ echo "$(( "$(ord c)" - "$(ord a)" ))"
2
```

If you wanted to put this in a function, you could:

```
diff_ord() { echo "$(( "$(ord $1)" - "$(ord $2)" ))"; }
```

Then call it like:

```
$ diff_ord c a
2
```

---

1. > If the leading character is a single-quote or double-quote, the value shall be the numeric value in the underlying codeset of the character following the single-quote or double-quote.

Comment: May I know, where the `'`-semantics is defined? It does not say so in neither the _printf_ man-page, nor int the description of printf in the _bash_ man-page, though I could verify that it indeed works as you described it.

Comment: @user1934428 From https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/printf.html#tag_04_102_13 
"If the leading character is a single-quote or double-quote, the value shall be the numeric value in the underlying codeset of the character following the single-quote or double-quote." I added a link to the answer.